# What is the Rails Way to perform a data update after a structural db change via db:migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm changing a relationship in my database from has_many to a has_many :through. So right now I have:

```
class Brand < Ar::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < AR::Base
  belongs_to :brand
end
```

and I'm going to add a join table.

But of course I need to update the database with data after that. I have seen that it is not good practice to do this in the confines of the migration. Where is the best place to perform this, knowing that I have to then run another migration after the data update is complete (i.e. removing the original brand_id column from the products table)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand your question, the migration is the place to make that transformation. The purpose of the migration is to change your schema and migrate existing data to use the schema. Migrations capture the temporal aspect of layering schema changes, so that you can go forward and backward in time without leaving data in an inconsistent state. If you were to migrate your rows anywhere else, you have no guarantee that when that code runs, the schema is as it was when you wrote your migration code.

I believe that you will find support for my position in the examples on the [Active Record Migrations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) api documentation. You might be confusing migrations with populating seed data (`rake db:seed`) which is handled in `db/seeds.rb`.

Comment: Looks like he wants to run a migration (add a join table), then manipulate the data in the tables, then run another migration after that.  seeds was added for seeding the initial data, but that is not what he is trying to acheive... he wants to manipulate existing data. Some argue that you should not manipulate the data in the tables with a migration.. only the table itself.

Comment: I would argue that the correct place to do this would be in a single migration. Run the change related to the first migration, migrate the data, then run the rest of the changes. If the three steps are coupled, such that any one should not happen independently, they should be contained within one migration.

Comment: I agree.  but maybe move the data manipulation to a separate ruby file or rake task.

Answer (score 2):

One-time changes like this can be done with ruby code in the migration. Migrations aren't just for schema changes. The idea is that migrations, by there version/datecode, are ensured to only be run once.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should at least include the call to the code (maybe a rake task) that runs the data manipulation within the migration, since you have to run the 2nd migration right after the data manipulation.

If it were me, I would create a rake task that manipulates the data.  This will at least remove the code from the migration and allow you to run it manually if it were ever necessary.  Then code your migration and include a call to that rake task.  I honestly don't see what the big deal is about not using data manipulation in a migration.  Especially when you have to do things in a specific order as you are doing.  They are tied so closely together, so why completely separate them?

Comment: I agree. I do not understand reservation migrating data with the schema. To my understanding this is the very purpose of migrations. Why would you want to have a rake task in your codebase that is only applicable at a very precise moment within a single commit?

Comment: Opinion aside, if you do not want to touch data inside of a migration then I would concur that a rake task is the appropriate vehicle.

Comment: You make a good point that the data manipulation is only applicable to this particular migration.  In this case it is unlikely that the rake task would be used at any other time.

Comment: Thanks everyone. That's what I ended up doing. I could only pick one answer, but I spread some votes around for all of you. I appreciate your help!

Comment: The reservation is that application code evolves over time, but no one ever looks at old migrations and maintaining them is no fun. To give a couple of examples, addition of validations or changing the name of a model at a later time may cause running migrations from scratch to fail.

A possible alternative could be to put your app in maintenance mode (Capistrano or the like), deploy, run your one-time data manipulation with IRB, then disable maintenance mode. Manual yes, but these are often cases you want to babysit anyway.